# PowerShell trying to convert to an integer instead of a string

Tags: excel, powershell, ini

My problem is that PowerShell wants to convert "=" into an integer, when trying to use it to make a new string. I made sure that my resulting variable would also be a string. Here's my task:

I have a little Excel table like this:

```
___________|VLANID1|VLANID2|VLANID3|
SwitchName1|    1-7|  12-16|   8-11| ← Ports 1-7 of Switch1 are configure for VLAN1...
SwitchName2|    1-7|  12-16|   8-11|
```

Out of this table I want to save each port in an .ini file with the VLAN it is configured too, aka:

```
[SwitchName1]
1=VLANID1
2=VLANID3
...
```

And here's my code which I loop until there are no ports, and then no more switches.

```bsh
$split = $global:Ports -split("-") #$Ports is the Value with the saved excel cell (7-11)
$split[0]..$split[1] | ForEach-Object {
    $vlan = $global:Switches.Cells.Item(1, $global:SSpallte).Text
    [string]$inistring = "`n" + $_ + "=" + $vlan #<- Here it tries to convert "=" into integer
    Add-Content -Path $global:portsini -Value $inistring
}
```

I even tried converting every variable which I use to make `$inistring` to a string before, it still doesn't work. Also, both `$_` and `$vlan` have a Value and are not `$null`.

The Error states that "=" cannot be converted into the type "System.Int32".

Comment: ``"`n" + $_ + "=" + $vlan`` -> `"${_}=${vlan}"`

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers What happens with the "`n"? Do I also put it in the String or if I can just leave it out, why would it now make a new line when I append it to a new file?

Comment: Nothing. `Add-Content` writes the string as a new line anyway, so the LF shouldn't be needed.

Comment: Ansgar's comment simplifies your approach, but your symptom remains a mystery: with a string as the first operand in the `+` operations all remaining operands should implicitly be converted to strings; try `"\`n" + 42 + "=" + 0`, for instance. There must be something you're not showing us. Is this the exact line that triggers the error, and what is the full error message? Please update your question directly.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey: While using `-f` may be a good idea in general, `+`-based string concatenation with a `[string]` as the LHS - as in the question - should always treat all subsequent operands as `[string]`s too - or are you aware of specific gotchas there?

Comment: while it does not directly concern your particular problem ... have you tried the `-f` string format operator? that would let you use `'{0}={1}' -f $PortNumber, $VlanName` and entirely avoid using string concatenation.  in my personal experience, avoiding _unintended addition_ [instead of concatenation] is a good reason to avoid the use of the `+` operator for building strings. [grin]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, im not quite sure what the problem was, but my way to solve it was to restart my environment. I am programming in the PowerShell ISE which I have sometimes seen "caching" variables. This restart of the ISE made the program work again.
And no, I didn't change anything beforehand.
In the end I'm happy that my problem is no more, but I'm still wondering why the error got triggered by the "=".

Comment: The ISE indeed runs repeated invocations of the same code in the same session, so that effects from previous runs may linger. That said, I too am wondering how the error you saw happened, given that even repeated invocations of the code in your question do not explain it.